# How to create Julia API without exposing implementation object

Tags: api, julia

I want to create an API in Julia without implementation object in function definition.

I want

```
result1 = do_something(arg1, arg2)
result2 = do_somethingelse(arg3)
```

instead of

```
obj = ImplementationObject()
result1 = do_something(obj, arg1, arg2)
result2 = do_somethingelse(obj, arg3)
```

I thought of this

```
module MyModule 
import objModule
obj = ImplementationObject()  

function do_something(arg1, arg2)
  do_something(obj, arg1, arg2)
end
end
```

I somehow feel that it's not the right way.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: I would take a look at how [DataStructures.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl) does it.

Comment: What is the intended role of the implementation object? Why do you need it at all? Does it need to store mutable state?

Comment: Consider the function `place_order(stock, 100)`. This function would internally use a brokerage object to implement this function but I don't want user to know anything about brokerage object. Also, there would just be one brokerage object.

Comment: So the order would be recorded in the brokerage object? In that case, why do you want to impose the limitation on the user to always use the same brokerage object?

Comment: Yes, I want the brokerage object to save the information about all the orders and don't want to keep the onus of creating one with the user. Is the design of creating const global like `const brokerage = Brokerage()`  efficient and correct way to do it in this case or is there another design method?

Comment: Yes, `const` globals are efficient (but non-const might not be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to restrict the user to always (implicitly) use the same implementation object, the above example seems fine.

If you provide a way for users to create their own implementation objects if desired, then the way that you have overloaded `do_something` also provides a default if the user does not specify it. This is similar to how eg `print` and `rand` in base Julia use a default output stream and random number generator, respectively, if you don't supply one.